# Unable to Create ODP Connection Because Visual Studio Keeps Converting the First Letter in Username to Uppercase

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, database-connection

Everytime I try to to create a new connection to database using ODP I get an 'invalid username/password' error because the first letter always changes to uppercase. I tried changing it from the 'advanced' option, but still no luck. Is there a way around it?

[image: the username is "d1800799' but the 'd' always becomes uppercase as soon as I move on to the next field]

Comment: you try putting it in "quotes" ? unless you went out of your way, oracle schema names are always UPPERCASE

Comment: kept on restarting VS until it finally worked. Thanks for the help!