# How do you set up Oracle Database Connection in VS Code Oracle Developer Tools extension?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can connect to our on-prem Oracle database via Oracle SQL Developer. The setup screen looks like this:

[image]

However, the same setup in the VS Code Oracle Developer Tools extension does not work. I get an error message: `Error opening connection 'USERNAME.SERVICENAME'. Details: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`.

The DB Connection screen in VS Code looks like this:[image]

There seem to be two problems:

1. My username is all lowercase, but it is changed to all uppercase in the DB Connection window in VS Code, i.e. username becomes USERNAME. There doesn't appear to be a way to change this. I attempted to place double quotes around my username, as recommended here: [Unable to Create ODP Connection Because Visual Studio Keeps Converting the First Letter in Username to Uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61188430/unable-to-create-odp-connection-because-visual-studio-keeps-converting-the-first), i.e. "username". But, that does not work.
2. The connection string in the VS Code extension appears to be incorrect. In Oracle Developer the string listed under connection details follows the pattern: username@//hostname:port/servicename. However in the VS Code extension the connection string is hostname:port/servicename. Maybe the username@// prefix is added on connection?

Can anyone troubleshoot or explain how to connect to the DB via the VS Code Oracle Developer Tools extension?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message you get when you try to connect? It's VERY unlikely you have a case sensitive username, so just putting in hr and that turns into HR is no problem.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, I've updated the question to include the error message: `Error opening connection 'USERNAME.SERVICENAME'. Details: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`. And, before anyone asks, a coworker has tried logging in with her credentials and gotten the same message, so it is unlikely that we've both repeatedly put in the wrong username and password.

Comment: passwords are case sensitive and some characters in a a password require double quotes...it's either that or you're not connecting to the right database - the error message is pretty clear on that.

Comment: If you are still having the issue, please leave another comment. There are some strange scenarios that can cause a ORA-1017 that are not obvious.  (FYI - The connection string is what is called a "Easy Connect" connection string. It is provided in case you want to use it elsewhere such as in application code)

Comment: Your organization might be set up similar to mine. I don’t know the specifics, but I think the configuration uses an external authentication plugin in OID with LDAP (or something). I have the same issue. A potentially-related issue is here: https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/254